# Pagination when div is overflowing

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, overflow

Is there a way to implement pagination like Googles "show more results" with jQuery (preferable with a plugin) when the content makes the div overflow?

In my case I'm working on an image sharing site and I'm using a div with fixed height and overflow: scroll (css) to show all the uploaded images, and instead of the scrolling I want to be able to use pagination. Normally with pagination you have several pages, but I only have on page for all the images.

**I only use one page for all the images.**

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to fit everything on one page or multiple pages, I do not understand your question.

Comment: I want to fit everything on one page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might not be the look you're going for, but you could try [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

It will stack the images as closely as possible to one-another and it has an [infinite scroll function](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need all images at one place ( I mean on the same page, neither google nor facebook does it)

When you scroll at bottom of page, they do an ajax request, fetch some more images / (posts in case of facebook) and append it to the container.

So, you need a container with height:auto. A function binded to window's scroll event, so that at bottom it can do an ajax request and add more images in website :)

*Does this help you or you need code ?*